# Customizable User interface website examples

Tags: jquery, html, css, widget, customization

I am looking for examples of sites that allow users to customize widges (resize, move widgets around, choose different layouts, etc..)

A great example is [netvibes.com](http://www.netvibes.com):

go to netvibes.com > get started > click on Go basic (you won't have to give your info) > and type any topic you like (world of warcraft for example) - It takes a minute then the dashboard loads and you can see how you can interact with the different widgets at the bottom of the page.

I am building a site that requires such functionalists, and I am mainly looking to see examples that are already out there for inspiration.

I understand the question I am asking doesn't have a right or wrong answer, so I guess I'll award the correct answer to whoever gives the best and the most relavent link(s).

Thanks

I've obviously searched google before posting here, and that's how I found netvibes. I want to know if anyone knows of something similar or better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to search on sites like this:

http://www.siteslike.com/similar/netvibes.com

http://www.similarsites.com/site/netvibes.com

http://www.similarsitesearch.com/alternatives-to/netvibes.com